# unable to connect database in Servlet JDBC Connection Pool using META-INF/context.xml file

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, jndi

I am trying to connect mysql database using Servlet using context.xml file.
By referring example provided on website:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/09/database-connection-pooling-tomcat-eclipse-db.html

But I am getting exception:
 javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc not bound

after that I have added  tag in web.xml, then also it didn't work and gave another exception as:

Error during deploy; - nested throwable: (javax.naming.NamingException: resource-ref: jdbc/mytest has no valid JNDI binding. Check the jboss-web/resource-ref.)

(Note:mytest is my database name)

**additional details: I have added my configuration detail for refernce**
*context.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <!-- Specify a JDBC datasource -->
    <Resource name="jdbc/mytest" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" username="root" password="mysql"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mytest"
        maxActive="10" maxIdle="4" />
</Context>
```

*web.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

  <display-name>testjdbc</display-name>
<resource-ref>
      <description>DB Connection</description>
      <res-ref-name>jdbc/mytest</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref> 

  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>TestServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mytest.TestServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/TestServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

*servlet.java :*

```
public void init() throws ServletException 
 {
        try 
        {
            // Get DataSource
            Context initContext  = new InitialContext();
            Context envContext  = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/jdbc/mytest");
            dataSource = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/mytest");

        } 
         catch (NamingException e) 
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you mentioned is for the Tomcat but you are now using jboss-web.

Each server may have slightly different way to configure the  JNDI Datasource .For the jboss-web , you can refer to [this](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) .

Comment: I have gone through this site, the settings are exactly same as tomcat for `context.xml` and `web.xml`.I don't know whether extra settings are needed in some other files.

Answer (score 0):

When the Datasource resource is defined with name="jdbc:testdb" in context.xml, you have to look up with that same name in your InitialContext.lookUp() method.  The databse name (mytest) shall be given in the connection url.

Comment: I have already written `jdbc:mytest` in `context.xml` also want to ask you that `initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env)` is correct or not. I am using linux system

Comment: It depends on the server you are using. In tomcat this is the jndi path, but in JBoss it will be like java:/<resource name>. Give your resource name like `jdbc/mytest` instead of `jdbc:mytest` and you will be able to get it by `java:/jdbc/mytest`

Comment: I have added my context.xml, web.xml and servlet file, can you check what is the mistake

Comment: Try like this : `InitialContext intCntx = new InitialContext();`
`DataSource ds = (DataSource) intCntx.lookup("java:/jdbc/mytest");`

Comment: Thank you very much for replying, but I am still getting same error:- Error during deploy; - nested throwable: (javax.naming.NamingException: resource-ref: jdbc/mytest has no valid JNDI binding. Check the jboss-web/resource-ref.)

Comment: Can you check your server startup logs and see if there is any error ? If there is any error while establishing connection, the datasource name wont be bound. And you can check the log with mytest and see what it is binding too.